# Jackson: Parse XML with attribute and child tag name conjunction

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I need to parse XML, containing node **child**, which shares the name **subject** for attribute of type `String` and unwrapped collection of type `Subject`.

Method `setSubject(Object value)` checks the type of the value given and maps it to either `String` or `Subject` field internally.

Method `XmlMapper.convertValue(Object from, Class<T> to)` fails on second attempt with the **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException** because **node** element is being treated as `LinkedHashMap` instead of `ArrayList` expected.

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList[com.example.MyTest$Node]` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
> at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN] (through reference chain: com.example.MyTest$Root["child"]-]com.example.MyTest$Child["subject"])

Any ideas why is working that way?

```java
@Test
void syntheticTest() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {

    String xml;
    Root root;

    // #1
    xml = """
            <root>
                <child subject="first subject">
                    <subject>
                        <node param="value1" />
                        <node param="value2" />
                    </subject>
                </child>
            </root>
            """;
    root = mapper.readValue(xml, Root.class);
    assertEquals(2, root.getChild().getSubjectObj().getNodes().size());

    // #2
    xml = """
            <root>
                <child subject="second subject">
                    <subject>
                        <node param="value1" />
                    </subject>
                </child>
            </root>
            """;
    root = mapper.readValue(xml, Root.class);
    assertEquals(1, root.getChild().getSubjectObj().getNodes().size());
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class Root {

    private Child child;

}

@Getter
public static class Child {

    private String subjectStr;

    private Subject subjectObj;

    public void setSubject(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof String str) {
            subjectStr = str;
        } else {
            subjectObj = mapper.convertValue(value, Subject.class); // <- #2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException
        }
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class Subject {

    @JsonProperty("node")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Node> nodes;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class Node {

    private String param;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Jackson deserializes a list with only one value as an object instead of an array, which causes your second example to fail. Set [`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) to `true`:

```java
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

Also see [Jackson deserialize single item into list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35201036/6573838).

Comment: Great tip. Didn't find that thread by myself, thank you